# Eclipse - Set minimum number of lines above or below cursor like in Vim?

Tags: eclipse, vim, scroll

In Vim you can set a minimum number of lines to keep above or below the cursor so that you don't have to move all the way to the bottom of the screen before scrolling occurs. (See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrolloff%27)

Is there a way to achieve this in Eclipse?